# Showing YouTube annotations - iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API to display an interactive video in a native iOS application. The interactivity of the video are hyperlinks placed throughout the video, providing the user with options to change the story.

However, when I tried creating such an application I cannot show annotations. How can I show these annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [YouTube help docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92710?hl=en), annotations are not supported by the IFrame API on mobile devices.

> Annotations do not appear on custom [YouTube chromeless players, or on mobile, tablet and TV devices.](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html)